# Android APK Supported device List shows Samsung Galaxy Y - GT-S5360 but In the Device Playstore My App not getting Display

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my App in Playstore, and I checked the APK Device Support List. Its shows Samsung Galaxy Y - GT-S5360. But when Browse through the Play store App it is not getting Displayed. Can you tell me what may be the Issue.

Below is my Manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- InApp Purchase Permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: How long since you uploaded your apk? It may take a while until you can find it in Google play.

Comment: It is about one month back I have uploaded. It is Display in all other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true" />
```